# Trouble with neon dot product on iPhone 4 and XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, neon

I am trying to implement a dot product function on the iPhone 4 using the neon. Based on this tutorial: http://www.delmarnorth.com/microwave/requirements/neon-test-tutorial.pdf
I tried the following below in XCode 4.5. When I set nruns=1 it works, i.e., I get the same answer from the neon as the standard C++ version. However, when I set nruns > 1 something gets corrupted and garbage comes out (e.g., if I print out the elements of the a array after the first call to dotProduct() they are corrupted). I have to confess I have no experience with the neon, but all I need is to be able to do this dot product! Anyone have any thoughts?

```
   float dotProduct ( float *a, float *b, int n) {
        float sum=0.0f;
        __asm__ volatile (
                          "vmov.f32 q8, #0.0               \n\t"
                          "vmov.f32 q9, #0.0               \n\t"
                          "1:                             \n\t"
                          "subs %3, %3, #8                \n\t"
                          "vld1.f32 {d0,d1,d2,d3}, [%1]!      \n\t"
                          "vld1.f32 {d4,d5,d6,d7}, [%2]!      \n\t"
                          "vmla.f32 q8, q0, q2              \n\t"
                          "vmla.f32 q9, q1, q3              \n\t"
                          "bgt 1b                         \n\t"
                          "vadd.f32 q8, q8, q9              \n\t"
                          "vpadd.f32 d0, d16, d17           \n\t"
                          "vadd.f32 %0, s0, s1              \n\t"
                          : "=w"(sum)
                          : "+r"(a), "+r"(b), "+r"(n)
                          : "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q8", "q9");
        return sum;
    }



    void test_dotProduct_neon()
    {
        int n=16, i, k;
        int nruns = 2;
        float dp;
        float *a = new float[n];
        float *b = new float[n];
        for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
           a[i] = (float) i; 
           b[i] = (float) (2*i);
        }
        for (i=0; i<nruns; i++) {
           dp=0.0f;
           for( k=0; k < n; k++) {
               dp += a[k] * b[k];
            }
        }
        printf(" C Result:   %f\n", dp );
        for (i=0; i<nruns; i++) {
            dp = dotProduct( a, b, n);
        }
        printf(" Neon Result:   %f\n", dp );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your NEON code modifies the pointers "a" and "b" since your load instructions (vld1) increment the address register (that's what the '!' after the address does).

Presumably, what is happening is that the compiler doesn't realize that those values might change, and thus your code works with bogus pointer values the second time around.

You do mark those inline assembly inputs with "+", which means "input/output operand", but I think you need to list them in the *output* operands section, not in the *input* operands second for that to work. Your code should read

```
: "=w"(sum), "+r"(a), "+r"(b), "+r"(n)
: /* No inputs */
: "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q8", "q9"
```

Also, the sets of input, output and clobbered registers are *not* disjoint! Marking a register as clobbered doesn't prevent the compiler from using it as an input register AFAIR, because it assumes that inputs are consumbed *before* clobbering takes place. Now, since your inputs are ARM registers and your clobbered registers as NEON register, you should be safe **if** the same isn't also true for output vs. clobbered registers. I recommend you check http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html to be sure.

**Edit:** Your code seems to be correct even if `sum` happens to live in one of the clobbered registers, since you never read it it write it only at the very end. I missed that previously when I wrote the warning above.

**Edit:** Your inline assembly passes the pointers `a` and `b` not as memory regions (with an `m`-Constraint), but as plain values in a general-purpose register. The compiler is therefore unaware that you're actually *reading* from those memory locations, and as a result might incorrectly move your assembly block past other stores to those locations. Now, since your memory region has variable size, you cannot easily use `m`-Constraints, since those assume that the size is determined statically. Instead, you can add `"memory"` to the clobber list, which tells the compiler that the assembly block reads and writes to and from arbitrary memory locations. And while you're at it, you should also add "`cc`", since your assembly block modifies the condition-code register (the register which contains the result of test instructions). The input/output declaration then looks the following

```
: "=w"(sum), "+r"(a), "+r"(b), "+r"(n)
: /* No inputs */
: "q0", "q1", "q2", "q3", "q8", "q9", "cc", "memory"
```

When writing inline assembly blocks, always remember that the compiler takes no, absolutely **no** look at the contents of such a block. It's only source of information about the block's behaviour and data-dependencies are the declarted input and output operands, and declared clobber list. And the compiler *will* use that information aggressively when optimizing, especially if you compile with `-O2` or higher. Thus, any omission in those declarations potentially causes the compiler to generate incorrect code.

Comment: I'm back. After playing around a lot more I realized I was still getting errors. I finally realized that my input vectors need to have a dimension of a power of 2. I should mention that I also miscopied the example in the tutorial I cited in the link, and that the actual code in that link mirrors the correction you suggested above. Anyway, now it works.

Comment: Why a power of 2? Their dimension needs to be divisible by 8, I'd say, since your NEON code processes the elements in chunks of 8. Your inline assembly, BTW, also fails to inform the compiler that you're actually reading from the memory pointed to by `a` and `b`. I'm going to do another edit to explain how to fix that.

Comment: Right again. Needs to be a multiple of 8. Looking forward to your edit.